# Error with IJCA article

Tags: errors, document-classes

I am writing an conference paper for IJCA. I did the initial steps. But I am getting some errors which I am not able to unerstand. I am attaching the code below. Can somebody help me out.

```
\documentclass{ijcaArticle}

\begin{document}

\title{Image Compression}
\author{xxx}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
image is an important method

\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

I am getting some errors when compiling

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\headingtable ...Name } \\ {Volume \ \@ijcaVolume
\ - No.\ \@ijcaNumber , \@...
l.12 \end{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply some additional information for the journal: Volume, Number, Year and Month.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ijcaArticle}

\title{Image Compression}
\author{xxx}
\ijcaVolume{12}
\ijcaNumber{7}
\ijcaYear{2014}
\ijcaMonth{Feb}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
image is an important method
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Class source: [`ijcaArticle.cls`](http://www.general-files.pw/download/gs60671d31h32i0/LatexSubmissionGuide.zip.html)